# Duplicate Strict-Transport-Security in web site

Tags: https, http-headers, iis-10

I was asked by our compliance team at work to add 'includeSubDomains' to the Strict-Transport-Security header for our site.  So I added the entry below (top one) to our .NET site's web config.  But when I did that, I see another Strict-Transport-Security entry (2nd one below) with only the max-age and a bigger value.

```
Strict-Transport-Security:
max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

Strict-Transport-Security:
max-age=157680000
```

My questions are:

1. Which one would the browsers obey?  (I'm hoping the one with the includeSubDomains)
2. Is there a way to remove the second one and how is it set?  My site is hosted in IIS 10 and I checked in the HTTP headers configuration and don't see where the 2nd one is set, only the top one is set there.

I googled around for dup headers to see what they say about this but can't find anything on my particular situation or how to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC 6797, 8.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-8.1), the browser must only process the first header:

> If a UA receives more than one STS header field in an HTTP response
> message over secure transport, then the UA MUST process only the first
> such header field.

The second header may be set at a different level. In IIS Manager, check whether the "HTTP Response Headers" module is configured at the server level.

If it's not in the IIS configuration, it could be added by some middleware, custom code, or security software. Check your application's code for any explicit headers being set.

Once you identify where the second header is coming from, you can modify the configuration or code to remove it or adjust its settings.

Comment: Thanks Yurong.  Checking the IIS settings at server level and app level was the first thing I did.   I also combed through my .NET code and could not find where it has been set(other than the 'includeSubdomain' entry that I put)

Comment: The HSTS header can only be set once. This is usually caused by a second HSTS header added by your hosting provider or another plugin. If your site is behind a load balancer or other network device, they may add headers. Or if your site uses a proxy server, they may add headers as well.